# c++ card game, hand being dealt more than once when a new round deck is created / new round is started

Tags: c++

I'm writing a video poker game and I'm having a problem with a hand being drawn and then replaced when a new round is started.

The idea is you start with five cards, you select which cards to keep and then the others are switched out when you click "deal", you will then be shown your new cards and told what you've won, after that you will be asked to start a new round, when you click "new round" the deck that was used previously should be discarded, a new hand taken from that deck and then drawn onto the screen.

The first two things work, the problem is that when I click "new round" it very quickly draws the hand to the screen and then replaces it with another hand, this doesn't effect the players bet, the money they have, absolutely nothing, it took me a while to notice that it was actually happening.

I can't post a working example, that would require the entire game to be uploaded (my code isn't very elegant) but I will try to show the relevant text.

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    //load static cards
    SDL_Surface* deal_card = load_surface("resources/images/cards/misc/deal.png");
    SDL_Surface* round_card = load_surface("resources/images/cards/misc/new_round.png");
    SDL_Surface* held = load_surface("resources/images/cards/effect/held.png");

    //initiate standard sdl modules
    if(!init())
    {
        printf("fail init");
    }
    //initiate SDL_ttf
    else if(TTF_Init() == -1)
    {
        printf("TTF INit fail");
    }
    else
    {
        //should exit
        bool quit = false;

        //events
        SDL_Event e;

        //font and font colour to be used for rendering text1
        TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("resources/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 18);
        SDL_Color text_colour = {236, 251, 100};

        //create a new deck, draw out a hand, sort it numerically, setup images and positions for cards
        vector<card>my_deck = new_shuffled_deck();
        vector<card>my_hand = hand(my_deck);
        sort_hand(my_hand);
        setup_hand(my_hand);

        //should switch cards that are not held and remove those used
        //must be TRUE on start otherwise the first deal will duplicate cards
        bool switch_hand = true;
        int round_number = 1;

        //get or set bet information
        read_bet(player_pot, cash_borrowed);

        while(!quit)
        {
            //starting mouse position
            int mouse_x_pos = 0;
            int mouse_y_pos = 0;
            //push current mouse position to starting mouse positions
            SDL_GetMouseState(&mouse_x_pos, &mouse_y_pos);

            //set up to blit hold icon
            update_hold_position(my_hand);

            //check for winning hand
            winning_hand hand_details = my_scores.card_check(my_hand, bet_amount);
            //setup render and blit text
            render_and_blit_text(font, hand_details, player_pot, cash_borrowed, text_colour);
            scoring_text(font, hand_details, text_colour);

            //switch out cards that are not held
            if(switch_hand == true)
            {
                swap_cards(my_hand, my_deck);
            }
            switch_hand = false;

            while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
            {
                if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
                if(e.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    //set mouse position to carry over without resetting
                    int n_mouse_pos_x = mouse_x_pos;
                    int n_mouse_pos_y = mouse_y_pos;
                    //check if card is clicked, if is selected de-select, if not selected then select
                    for(size_t cpc = 0; cpc < my_hand.size(); cpc++)
                    {
                        // if mouse position is in range of left side of card and right side of card
                        if(n_mouse_pos_x > my_hand[cpc].position.x and n_mouse_pos_x < my_hand[cpc].position.x + my_hand[cpc].image->w &&
                           n_mouse_pos_y > my_hand[cpc].position.y and n_mouse_pos_y < my_hand[cpc].position.y + my_hand[cpc].image->h)
                        {
                            //if clicked un-click, if un-clickde click
                            if(my_hand[cpc].selected == 0)
                            {
                                my_hand[cpc].selected = 1;
                            }
                            else if(my_hand[cpc].selected == 1)
                            {
                                my_hand[cpc].selected = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if deal is clicked
                    if(n_mouse_pos_x > deal_rect.x and n_mouse_pos_x < deal_rect.x + deal_card->w &&
                       n_mouse_pos_y > deal_rect.y and n_mouse_pos_y < deal_rect.y + deal_card->h)
                    {
                        //switch held cards, if last round switch entire hand, update cash
                        deal_clicked(switch_hand, round_number, my_hand, my_deck, cash_borrowed, player_pot, amount_won,
                                     bet_amount, hand_details);
                    }
                }
            }
            //blit section
            //blit cards to screen
            blit_cards(my_hand, round_number, held, screen_surface, deal_rect, round_card, deal_card);

            SDL_Surface* fill_screen;
            fill_screen = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0, screen_width, screen_height, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_FillRect(screen_surface, 0, SDL_MapRGB(fill_screen->format, 18, 17, 233));

            SDL_FreeSurface(fill_screen);

            SDL_Delay(30);
        }
    }
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

Swap cards:

```
void swap_cards(vector<card>&my_hand, vector<card>&my_deck)
{
    for(size_t b = 0; b < my_hand.size(); b++)
    {
        if(my_hand[b].selected == false)
        {
            SDL_FreeSurface(my_hand[b].image);
            //replace card with card of the same index from the deck
            my_hand[b] = my_deck[b];
            // remove card from deck so it cannot be chosen again
            my_deck.erase(my_deck.begin() + b);
        }
        else
        {
            // this prevents memory leak on held cards, no idea why.
            SDL_FreeSurface(my_hand[b].image);
        }
    }
    //set up images and position for cards again
    setup_hand(my_hand);
}
```

Deal clicked:

```
void deal_clicked(bool &switch_hand, int &round_number, vector<card>&my_hand,  vector<card>&my_deck,
                  int &cash_borrowed, int &player_pot, int &amount_won, int& bet_amount, winning_hand &hand_details)
{
    switch_hand = true;
    round_number++;
    // aka if(round_number % 2 == 0 and round_number != 0)
    if(round_number == 3)
    {
        //free card surface images
        for(size_t d = 0; d < my_hand.size(); d++)
        {
            SDL_FreeSurface(my_hand[d].image);
        }

        vector<card>().swap(my_deck);
        //replace deck with new deck
        my_deck = new_shuffled_deck();

        //draw new hand
        vector<card>().swap(my_hand);
        my_hand = hand(my_deck);
        //sort hand by card number
        sort_hand(my_hand);
        //load images and position cards
        setup_hand(my_hand);

        //set round number back to beginning
        round_number = 1;

        //distribute winnings and take next bet amount
        amount_won = hand_details.hand_score;
        if(cash_borrowed > 0)
        {
            cash_borrowed -= amount_won;
        }
        else if(cash_borrowed < 0)
        {
            player_pot += abs(cash_borrowed);
            cash_borrowed = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            player_pot += amount_won;
        }
        if(player_pot <= 0)
        {
            cash_borrowed +=5;
        }
        else
        {
            player_pot -= bet_amount;
        }
        write_bet(player_pot, cash_borrowed);
    }
}
```

Hopefully that should be enough for someone to have an idea about where my problem is coming from.

If anyone wants more code I can post it, it jut gets even more messy, these are the only areas I *think* could be causing the problem, then again I can't figure out what it is.

EDIT:

Solved, duplicate call to the setup_hand function.

Comment: So you didn't use your debugger to debug the code?

Comment: I'm very new to c++, I have no idea how that works, I've tried various things, changing when the cards switch, what method is used to decide if they should switch and many other little tweaks, that's about all I know how to do.

Comment: Well now is the best time to learn to use the tools that come with your compiler.  The debugger allows you to step through your code a single statement at a time.  Then you can see where your logic is going wrong, or at least where it deviates from what you had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate call to setup_hand function.